# Why Backup database is terminating abnormally in WPF with c#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, ado.net-entity-data-model

[image]

[image]

I am using this command to backing up my database in my wpf application in this application i am using ado.net entity data model database first approach so after executing command i am getting this Error Please guide why it happens ??

Comment: try running visual studio as administrator

Comment: Can u please give the code in Plain text .So that i try .

Comment: here are some reason behind Its occurrence: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/zoras-sql-tips/2016/07/30/reasons-for-backup-failure-in-sql-server-and-their-prevention/

Answer (score 2):

"Access is Denied" means that the user the database service is running under does not have access to that backup file, which is probably only writable by your *user* since it's under your user directory.

Update the security settings of your file/folder so that the database process's user (probably `SYSTEM`, `LOCAL SERVICE`, `NETWORK SERVICE` or similar) can write to that file. Or host the backup file somewhere else where SQL Server has access.